# How to filter csv file?

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a csv file containing random data but I want to filter the data from the file.
I want to filter all rows that have contents starting with $ and ending with #

```
2017-09-07 03:11:03,5,hello
2017-09-07 03:11:16,6,yellow
2017-09-07 03:11:22,28,some other stuff with spaces
2017-09-08 20:24:36,157,
        2017-10-28 04:39:25,54,$SITE0011,1654,0000,0000,0000,00000000,000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#
        2017-10-28 04:39:48,108,$SITE0011,1654,0000,0000,0000,00000000,000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#$SITE0011,1654,0000,0000,0000,00000000,000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#
        2017-10-28 04:40:26,54,$SITE0011,1654,0000,0000,0000,00000000,000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#
        2017-10-28 04:40:29,54,$SITE0011,1654,0000,0000,0000,00000000,000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're going after. Could you maybe show the expected output from the above example input?

Comment: I simply filter row like this                                                                      2017-10-28 04:39:25,54,$SITE0011,1654,0000,0000,0000,00000000,000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#

Comment: Do you mean to "exclude" those lines or "include" them when you say filter?

Comment: I include only those lines in my csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be a nice use case for a filtering generator function:

```
import re
import csv


def filter_lines(f):
    """this generator funtion uses a regular expression
    to include only lines that have a `$` and end with a `#`.
    """
    filter_regex = r'.*\$.*\#$'
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = re.match(filter_regex, line)
        if m:
            yield line


with open(CSV_FILENAME) as f:
    filter_generator = filter_lines(f)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(filter_generator)
    for row in csv_reader:
        pass
```

EDIT:

I realize now that in your example a single "line" could contain multiple matches (as seen on line 6). This slightly modified version can handle that just as well:

```
import re
import csv


def filter_lines(f):
    """this generator funtion uses a regular expression
    to include only lines that have a `$` and end with a `#`.
    """
    filter_regex = r'(\$[^#]*\#)'
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        matches = re.findall(filter_regex, line)
        for m in matches:
            yield m


with open(CSV_FILENAME) as f:
    filter_generator = filter_lines(f)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(filter_generator)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print row
```

Output generated from your example input:

```
['$SITE0011', '1654', '0000', '0000', '0000', '00000000', '000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#']
['$SITE0011', '1654', '0000', '0000', '0000', '00000000', '000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#']
['$SITE0011', '1654', '0000', '0000', '0000', '00000000', '000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#']
['$SITE0011', '1654', '0000', '0000', '0000', '00000000', '000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#']
['$SITE0011', '1654', '0000', '0000', '0000', '00000000', '000000^A^A^A^A^A^A^@^@#']
```

Comment: Hey @smassey in my csv file there are many unwanted data and when I use your code it returns UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 826: invalid start byte error.

Comment: Hi @vipulgangwar encoding errors are the biggest PITA that I have with python 2. At what line does is the UnicideDecodeError raised? I suspect that changing `yield m` to `yield unicode(m).encode('utf-8')` could resolve your issue.

Comment: Hey @smassey your suggest code work fine but I want also 2017-10-28 04:39:25,54 these two fields with other fields.